# What are the minimum and maximum values of $a+b+c$, given $\log|a|+\log|b|+\log|c|=0$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

For integers $a$, $b$ and $c$, what would  be the minimum and maximum values of $a+b+c$ if $\log|a|+\log|b|+\log|c|=0$?

**Given possibilities:**
$(a)\ -3\  \text{and}\ 3\quad $ $(b)\ -1\  \text{and}\ 1\quad $ $(c)\ -1\  \text{and}\ 3\quad $ $(d)\ 1\  \text{and}\ 3\quad $

**My trial:**

$$\log|abc|=\log1\\
|abc|=1\\
abc=1 \text{ or } abc=-1$$
For maxima of $a+b+c$ we know $a=b=c$ then $a^3=1\implies a=1=b=c$

$\therefore a+b+c=1+1+1=3$

For minima of $a+b+c$ we know $a=b=c$ then $a^3=-1\implies a=-1=b=c$

$\therefore a+b+c=-1-1-1=-3$.

Thus the correct option is (a). Please explain if I am wrong. Is there another, easier way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. I'm fairly certain that there in no easier way to solve this.